# Bind multiple request parameters to one object in Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I can't figure out a way to bind several arguments and headers to one request parameter using annotations in Spring 3.

For example, let's say I'm getting this request:

```
Headers:
Content-type: text/plain;

POST Body:
Name: Max
```

Now I want it all to mysteriously bind to this object:

```
class NameInfo {
    String name;
}
```

Using some code like this:

```
String getName() {
    if ("text/plain".equals(headers.get("content-type"))) {
        return body.get("name");
    } else if ("xml".equals(headers.get("content-type")) {
        return parseXml(body).get("name");
    } else ...
}
```

So that in the end I would be able to use:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
void processName(@RequestAttribute NameInfo name) {
...
}
```

Is there a way to achieve something similar to what I need?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@RequestBody` is what you want, I think. See the Spring docs about it [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody).

> The `@RequestBody` method parameter
>   annotation indicates that a method
>   parameter should be bound to the value
>   of the HTTP request body.
>
> You convert the request body to the
>   method argument by using an
>   `HttpMessageConverter`.
>   `HttpMessageConverter` is responsible
>   for converting from the HTTP request
>   message to an object.